# What is the logic of using $($(nproc) + 1) in make command?

Tags: make, cpu, jobs

I was trying to install OpenCV in Ubuntu based on few guides online. One of the guides is [this one](https://gist.github.com/filitchp/5645d5eebfefe374218fa2cbf89189aa). It has the following line:

```
make -j $(($(nproc) + 1))
```

The `nproc` returns the number of processors/ threads available on the system. So, what is the advantage of going one higher than what's available?

Comment: Related: [How to determine the maximum number to pass to make -j option?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208568/how-to-determine-the-maximum-number-to-pass-to-make-j-option)

Comment: @steeldriver I did see this one. But I was trying to see if I can get a more specific answer about going higher part in this specific context so that I can use that knowledge for future builds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most builds are I/O-limited, not CPU-limited, so while `nproc` is a decent starting point (see also [How to determine the maximum number to pass to make -j option?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/208568/86440)), most builds can use more than that. This is especially true if you’re using small VMs to build, which you’ll often find on build farms; there you’d end up with `-j 1` or `-j 2`, and using `-j 2` or `-j 3` will usually result in shorter build times without the risk associated with a formula such as `$(nproc) * 2` (which could cause problems even on an 8-thread system, let alone the larger thread counts you find on servers).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I still haven't quite understood how number of I/O jobs are tied to `nproc`. It seems like a technical topic that requires some research to develop a better intuition. Can you kindly provide some literature or books or other resources on the topic?

Comment: They’re not tied to `nproc`. That’s the whole point of `$(nproc) + 1`. Starting from the beginning, if you run a linear build on a current system (or even a fifteen-year-old system), your CPU will be idle most of the time; so you want to increase the number of jobs run in parallel. The real limit on build time however isn’t CPU capacity, it’s I/O capacity, but there’s no handy metric to determine that. So `nproc` is a proxy: it tells you how many jobs you can run in parallel without exhausting your CPU resources at least. Adding one is a common technique to use a bit more CPU...